# If $f:G \to H$ is an injective homomorphism of groups and $a \in G$, prove that $\vert f(a) \vert = \vert a \vert$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

The problem: If $f:G \to H$ is an injective homomorphism of groups and $a \in G$, prove that $\vert f(a) \vert = \vert a \vert$.

The solution in the back of the text first shows that if the order of $a$ is $n$, then the order of $f(a)$ must be $n$.  Then it shows that if the order of $f(a)$ is $n$ then the order of $a$ must be $n$, and in this second part it uses the fact that $f$ is an injection.

In any case, in attempting to do the problem on my own, I got hung up on the fact that the order of $a$ or $f(a)$ could be infinite, but I believe the text's solution addresses this.  By proving that $a$ has finite order $n$ iff $f(a)$ has finite order $n$, the text has also proved that that if one has infinite order, then so does the other.

Comment: It sounds like you understand this already, is there a question that anyone could help with?

Comment: Thank you, Suzu, I just wanted to make sure there was no error in my logic.